# Why don't electrons return to their ground state immediately after photoexcitation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, luminosity

In terms of photoluminescence, why don't the electrons, which have been excited by photons earlier, immediately fall down to their ground state and reemit a photon?

In other words, why does 'glow-in-the-dark' persist for a period of time? What causes the electrons to stay at a higher energy state and decay **slowly**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does stuff glow in the dark?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12116/)

Comment: The answers to the question I've linked address this. tl;dr the electrons end up in a triplet state and the triplet to singlet (ground) state is spin forbidden and hence very slow.